# Правильно ли расставил запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Путь туристов, был труден, зато вёл к намеченной цели.

Answer (score 4):

Первая запятая не нужна, так как между подлежащим и сказуемым нет никаких требующих обособления оборотов.

*Путь туристов был труден, зато вёл к намеченной цели.*